# Erro Android com KSOP2 com valor Double java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize:4.0

Tags: java, android, web-service, soap, ksoap2

Pessoal eu criei um webservice soap em java, eu consumo e realizo operações em vários métodos, entretanto quando vou realizar operações passando um valor double ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: <Valor double>
```

Segue o erro completo:

```
                E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1815
                Process: br.com.estudoemvideo, PID: 16300
                java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 4.0
                at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:784)
                at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:764)
                at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:688)
                at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBodyWithAttributes(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:664)
                at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:777) 
                at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:634)
                at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.write(SoapEnvelope.java:205)
                at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:153)
                at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:149)
                at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
                at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
```

Estou utilizando a biblioteca KSOAP2 para consumir o webservice.

Comment: Resolvi o meu problema, mas não é uma solução para o erro.
Toquei o tipo de dado do webservice para String, e no meu método webservice  eu converto de String para double. Funcionou para mim mas não é o jeito correto de fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu tive o mesmo problema e resolvi usando a solução do link abaixo, vou colar o post aqui caso ele pare de funcionar.

Basicamente, depois de você montar o seu envelope, você precisa serializar ele para que o processo funcione corretamente.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11718886/3347923

> To be exact use it like this
>
> the Marshal class
>
> ```
> import org.ksoap2.serialization.Marshal;
> import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
> import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
> import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
> import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
> import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;
>
> import java.io.IOException;
>
>
> public class MarshalDouble implements Marshal {
>   public Object readInstance(XmlPullParser parser, String namespace, String name,
>                              PropertyInfo expected) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
>
>       return Double.parseDouble(parser.nextText());
>   }
>
>
>   public void register(SoapSerializationEnvelope cm) {
>       cm.addMapping(cm.xsd, "double", Double.class, this);
>
>   }
>
>
>   public void writeInstance(XmlSerializer writer, Object obj) throws IOException {
>       writer.text(obj.toString());
>   }
> }
>
> the implementation
>
> SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
> envelope.implicitTypes = true;
> envelope.dotNet = true;
> envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
> envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
>
> **MarshalDouble md = new MarshalDouble();
> md.register(envelope);**
> ```